# How to interface USB to SPI communication in Windows.?

Tags: python, windows, usb, spi, converters

I have a `usb` to `spi` converter. I have attached it to windows 10 machine and need to work on this. I have connected this to `omron` thermal sensor which works on SPI and because windows doesnt have any `spi`, thus I have used `usb` to `spi` converter. The converter's manufacturer is `FTDI`.

If I open device manager, I do not see any `COM` port taken this converter. I can only see `USB to Serial Converter` showing under USB:

[image]

My plan was to use this python library [usb-iss](https://pypi.org/project/usb-iss/) but because it doesn't have any `COM` port, I am not sure how can I start fetching data from this converter. Can anyone please help and suggest some good soultions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The converter's manufacturer is FTDI. [...]
>   My plan was to use this python library usb-iss

Then you bought the wrong hardware. The usb-iss module requires usb-iss hardware based on a microchip pic µC.

For FTDI hardware one would use ftd2xx or LibFTDI - there are pyhton wrappers for these (ftd2xx, pylibftdi). The ftd2xx library uses FTDI drivers, while LibFTDI uses LibUSB drivers.

Comment: Some of FTDI chips also might have SPI interface. How are you sure it's a wrong hardware? Rather library might be wrong for the hardware at hand. In any case I have played only with Diolan serial bus extenders, so don't know much about FTDI.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have used pylibftdi and I can see ftdi device connected in python script. Just wanted to know, how can I send commands which omron sensor needs using pylibftdi. Can you point me to some good article. Thanks